# How to get rid of duplicates after combining 2 tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am new to sqlplus.I need to get rid of duplicates.That is, i don't want combinations of 2 tables.

```
 select CLUB.NAME as Club_NAME,
   CLUB.PHONE as Club_PHONE,
   CUSTOMER.FIRSTNAME as CUST_NAME,
  CUSTOMER.PHONE as CUST_PHONE,
 from CUSTOMER,CLUB ;
```

I just want the club names with there phonenumbers and same for customers(name and phone) from different tables(CLUB and customer).and not there combination.

I cannot use group by as i have not used any computation here

```
group by Club_NAME,CUST_NAME;
```

(ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression).

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use UNION ALL

```
SELECT CLUB.NAME as NAME,
   CLUB.PHONE as PHONE, 
   'CLUB' as TYPE
FROM CLUB
UNION ALL
SELECT  CUSTOMER.FIRSTNAME,
  CUSTOMER.PHONE,
  'CUSTOMER'
FROM CUSTOMER ;
```

This will get you all the customers and clubs with their respective phones.

I added an extra column of "TYPE" in case you want to identify from wich table the data came from. IF you don't need it, you can just remove it.

By removing that column, it also means that if you have the same record in both tables, you will not get it twice.

EDIT:

If you want to get the results in different columns, you can either do separate queries for each table, or you can do a union all, and return 4 columns, but when you are referring customers, the columns about clubs will be null.

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT CLUB.NAME as CLUBNAME, 
  CLUB.PHONE as CLUBPHONE,
  null AS CUSTOMERNAME,
  null AS CUSTOMERPHONE
FROM CLUB
UNION ALL
SELECT null,
  null,
  CUSTOMER.FIRSTNAME,
  CUSTOMER.PHONE
FROM CUSTOMER ;
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff2bd/13)

Comment: There's trailing commas @RajathAradhya; your client will direct you to the line and column that the problem occurs in that error message.

Comment: I re read the question and i'm not sure he means that kind of duplicates. He doesn't want the combination. But you are right if there are customers and clubs with the same name and phone number, they will get returned. @RajathAradhya. Like it is now works for you?

Comment: `select a, b, from c` is not valid syntax @Rajath; change it to `select a, b from c`. There's one less comma.

Comment: @filipe silva  you understood my question but i am getting error in your code

Comment: @filipe silva no it is not.

Comment: @RajathAradhya. Ah. At first there was a typo with an extra ',' character, but i removed it. So it is doing what you wanted?

Comment: @filipe silva ORA-00904: "CLUB": invalid identifier.club is a table name..so how can i use like that??

Comment: @RajathAradhya. see this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0f00/1) I think the problem was the double quotes. I updated my answer with the new query. This one should work

Comment: @RajathAradhya. If you feel this answered your question, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Ya that did work. But i need it in different columns.because i cannot merge those in a single column.

Comment: @RajathAradhya. I added a different approach for this. see if it helps